# UDP Packets can be visualized in Wireshark but unable to read using Python script

Tags: python, sockets, wireshark, ethernet

I'm sending data from a microcontroller (MCU) to a PC via ethernet port  I can successfully verify the data transmission using Wireshark, but my Python script is unable to read it.

I'm sending data to MCU using python script (which is working fine) and expecting response from MCU (Microcontroller)

Response from MCU is transmitted to PC using Ethernet and data can be seen  in Wireshark

Configuration for IPv4 in PC

IPv4 Address : 192.168.0.3
Subnet Mask : 255.255.255.0
Default gateway : 192.168.0.1

Configuration for Microcontroller

```
#define ETHERNET_CONF_IPADDR0                         192
#define ETHERNET_CONF_IPADDR1                         168
#define ETHERNET_CONF_IPADDR2                         0
#define ETHERNET_CONF_IPADDR3                         2


#define ETHERNET_CONF_GATEWAY_ADDR0                   192
#define ETHERNET_CONF_GATEWAY_ADDR1                   168
#define ETHERNET_CONF_GATEWAY_ADDR2                   0
#define ETHERNET_CONF_GATEWAY_ADDR3                   250

/** The network mask being used. */
#define ETHERNET_CONF_NET_MASK0                       255
#define ETHERNET_CONF_NET_MASK1                       255
#define ETHERNET_CONF_NET_MASK2                       255
#define ETHERNET_CONF_NET_MASK3                       0
```

Script

```
import socket

def receive_udp_data(host, port):
    # Create a UDP socket
    udp_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

    # Bind the socket to the specified host and port
    udp_socket.bind((host, port))
    print(f"Listening for UDP data on {host}:{port}")

    try:
        while True:
            # Receive data from the socket
            data, addr = udp_socket.recvfrom(1024)

            # Print the received data
            print(f"Received data from {addr}: {data.decode('utf-8')}")

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Stopping UDP listener...")
    finally:
        # Close the socket when done
        udp_socket.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Set the host and port to listen on
    host = "192.168.0.3"  # Listen on all available interfaces
    port =1234  # Choose a suitable port

    # Start listening for UDP data
    receive_udp_data(host, port)
```

Comment: Neither of the IP addresses you show from the microcontroller code is either your PC's address or a broadcast address, so how exactly is the PC supposed to receive anything?  (The Wireshark capture of one of these packets would be useful, so that we can see exactly what destination address is being used.)

Comment: @jasonharper Please find the link for Wireshark capture  @ https://imgur.com/a/EUT3KWk

Comment: Your capture clearly shows that your microcontroller is sending malformed packets (length field in IP header is incorrect).  I'm not surprised that your PC is ignoring these packets.

Comment: Thank you , I corrected my mistake in the code but I'm encountering other issue whenever I transmit 22 bytes of UDP Payload ,
Total length equates to 50 Bytes (20 Bytes of IP Header+  8 Bytes of UDP Header + 22 Bytes of UDP Data).

Wireshark Capture Says,
In IPv4 Section,
 Total Length=50,
Error Info : IPV4 total length exceeds packet length (46 Bytes).

In UDP Section the following error  is present 
Length=30 (bogus, payload length 26).

Bad length value 30 > IP Payload Length

For data section - UDP Payload is 18 Bytes.